# dynamically access nested json property using DataWeave

Tags: dataweave

I need to transform with dynamic access/extract to fields

```
{
    "simple" : "ab",
   "nestone": [
    {    
     "value": "zzz"
    }
  ],  
 "nesttwo": [
    {
    "val": {
        "nesttwoval": [
        {
            "value": "zzz"
        }
        ]
    }
    }
]

}
```

I need the output as below. s1 and n1 can be achieved using . notation
"s1" : payload.simple,
"n1" : payload.nestone.value,
but third nest one I can't extract. Any insight would be helpful

```
{
  "s1": "ab",
  "n1": [
    "zzz"
  ],
  "n2": null
}
```

Comment: you can access the element using payload.nesttwo.val.nesttwoval and so on and so forth.. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Or you could do  payload..nesttwoval

Comment: The input you have and the output you want, both are very unclear. Can you please update the expected output. Also please explain the input too, Are you not expecting any consistency in your input payload's structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on another comment you made, I don't think what you're asking for is built into the language, though there are some interesting functions in the library related to the `update` function. A basic implementation of what you want might look like this:

```
%dw 2.0
fun getField(payload: Any, field: String) = do {
    var path = field splitBy '.' reduce((pathPart, path=[]) ->
        if (pathPart contains '[') do {
            var pieces = pathPart splitBy '['
            ---
            pieces reduce((piece,subPath=path) -> 
                if (piece contains ']') subPath << (piece replace ']' with '') as Number
                else subPath << piece
            )
        }
        else path << pathPart
    )
    ---
    getField(payload, path)
}
fun getField(payload: Any, field: Array) =
    if (sizeOf(field) == 1) payload[field[0]]
    else getField(payload[field[0]], field[1 to -1])
```

So a call with this input:

```json
{
   "names": [
     {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Smith"
     },
     {
         "firstName": "John",
         "lastName": "Doe"
     }
   ]
}
```

And

```
getField(payload, "names[0].firstName")
```

Would return "BoB"

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike!. it is interesting .Right.  update is able to change multilevel nested field and equivalent version was not in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    s1: payload.simple,
    n1:payload.nestone.value,
    n2: payload..nesttwoval..value
}
```

Comment: Thanks I wnat to access dynamically using below 
```
fun recursiveLookup(lookupKey="", lookupObj) = if (lookupKey contains ".") recursiveLookup(substringAfter(lookupKey, "."), lookupObj[substringBefore(lookupKey, ".")]) else lookupObj[lookupKey]
```
and calling by  
```  recursiveLookup('nestwo.value',payload) ```  Is it achievable?

Comment: You need to have a consistency in your input or a way to define that. For e.g. they keys that you generate s1 , n1,n2 are not derived from your input. As well would your logic be to get the value stored in the key named "value" , which would then be assigned to a key that you handcraft in your script? For keys that don't have "value" as a nested key you simply assign the value that they have in the object to the output key ?  - For e.g. simple is not nested and has the value ab and thus s1 in the output would have value "ab" ?

Comment: Also if you are putting out code snippets in here , either put them in your question as a suggestion (if you could use that or something to that effect) , or as an answer block. Please avoid pasting code snippets in comments .

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this maybe:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings


fun returnValue(item) = 
    item match { 
        case is Array -> (($ map { a: $..value }).a)[0]
        case is Object -> (($ mapObject { a: $..value }).a)[0]
        else -> $
        }
---
payload mapObject {
    "s$$$": returnValue($)

/*payload mapObject {
    (($$ [0])++ ($$$+1)): returnValue($)

}/* dynamic key in the output

}
```